# Manual entry of SQL Data - ideal application

Tags: sql-server

As I've recently moved to x64 my SQL tool for manually editing/adding SQLServer database entries [SQL Buddy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlbuddy/) seems to getting massively long in the tooth (.Net 1), are there any (free) alternatives which are more up to date?

Just need a quick tool, for when writing an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statement is too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing about what Buddy can do but I think you should have a look at [SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b).

Manually editing table rows can be done with right-click on table and select "Edit top 200 rows". If 200 is not enough it can be configured to a higher value.

Comment: @wonea If you have lots (I mean LOTS) of entries, say in an Excel sheet, you might consider using SSIS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx

Comment: Simple as it sounds, but that SQL Management option passed me by.  Thanks!